# Loading js file and updating content every X seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a piece of JS code that displays and array of data in the frontend. Looks like this:

```
var compliments = {
    complimentLocation: '.compliment',
    currentCompliment: '',
    complimentList: {
        'morning': mycompliments.morning,
        'afternoon': mycompliments.afternoon,
        'evening': mycompliments.evening
    },
    updateInterval: mycompliments.interval || 30000,
    fadeInterval: mycompliments.fadeInterval || 4000,
    intervalId: null
};

compliments.updateCompliment = function () {

    var _list = [];

    var hour = moment().hour();

    if (hour >= 3 && hour < 12) {
        _list = compliments.complimentList['morning'].slice();
    } else if (hour >= 12 && hour < 17) {
        _list = compliments.complimentList['afternoon'].slice();
    } else if (hour >= 17 || hour < 3) {
        _list = compliments.complimentList['evening'].slice();
    } else {
        Object.keys(compliments.complimentList).forEach(function (_curr) {
            _list = _list.concat(compliments.complimentList[_curr]).slice();
        });
    }

    var _spliceIndex = _list.indexOf(compliments.currentCompliment);
    if (_spliceIndex !== -1) {
        _list.splice(_spliceIndex, 1);
    }

    var _randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * _list.length);
    compliments.currentCompliment = _list[_randomIndex];

    $('.compliment').updateWithText(compliments.currentCompliment, compliments.fadeInterval);

}

compliments.init = function () {

    this.updateCompliment();

    this.intervalId = setInterval(function () {
        this.updateCompliment();
    }.bind(this), this.updateInterval)

}
```

The last function gets triggered on page load and **grabs the content of `var compliments` from an external js file**.

What I'm trying to do is to include a timeout, so that the external file gets reloaded every X seconds, and the content displayed in the frontend replaced.

I've tried adding this timeout function at the end of the file (so it gets triggered on page load, and with the timeout afterwards) but so far no luck:

```
function functionToLoadFile(){
  jQuery.get('js/mycompliments.js', function(data) {

      compliments.init = function () {

        this.updateCompliment();

        this.intervalId = setInterval(function () {
            this.updateCompliment();
        }.bind(this), this.updateInterval)

      }

   setTimeout(functionToLoadFile, 1000);
});
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Wouldn't      setInterval be of better use in this situation? e.g. setInterval(functionToLoadFile, 1000);

Then just move it out of the functionToLoadFile and start it on page load.


Also doesn't the functionToLoadFile just set compliments.init many times, without actually doing anything itself.

Comment: well... you are doing nothing with the data you get from 'mycompliments.js' , just (re)defining the 'init' function of 'compliment' object(this function has also an interval function, I don't think it would be a good idea if you call it inside 'functionToLoadFile' function) and you are calling it the GET every second. Maybe you should call updateCompliment with 'data' as parameter...